# Color Changing Cycle function gets stuck on blue

Tags: python

I've created a game with pygame, and I have some food that I want to change color every time it is repositioned, however they only way it works is with a pretty inconsistent sequence of if statements from chat gpt.

```
def change_color(self):
    #if the food is green (with room for inexact)
    if self.color[0] >= 10 and self.color[1] >= 245 and self.color[2] >= 10:
        #change it to blue
        self.color = (0, 0, 255)
    #if the foods blue value is above zero and other values are
    elif self.color[0] == 0 and self.color[1] == 0 and self.color[2] != 0:
        #make it red
        self.color = (255, 0, 0)
    #if its red
    elif self.color[0] == 255 and self.color[1] == 0 and self.color[2] == 0:
        #Change to greenish
        self.color = (100, 250, 100)
    self.reposition()
```

I want it to cycle through green to blue to red and then back again, however when it change it to what seems correct to me, it get stuck on certain colors.

```
def change_color(self):
    #if the food is green (with room for inexact)
    if self.color[0] >= 10 and self.color[1] >= 245 and self.color[2] >= 10:
        #change it to blue
        self.color = (0, 0, 255)
    #if the foods blue value is above zero and other values are
    elif self.color[0] >= 10 and self.color[1] >= 10 and self.color[2] >= 245:
        #make it red
        self.color = (255, 0, 0)
    #if its red
    elif self.color[0] >= 245 and self.color[1] >= 10 and self.color[2] >= 10:
        #Change to greenish
        self.color = (0, 255, 0)
    self.reposition()
```

when I run this it gets stuck on blue...
not sure whats happening.
Thank you all in advance :)

Comment: It can only go red or green when `self.color[1] >= 10`, so that won't happen when it's currently blue, i.e. `(0, 0, 255)`.

Comment: Even if you "fixed" this, ChatGPT's approach is pretty janky here. Instead do something like `COLORS=[(0,0,255), (255,0,0), (0,255,0)]`. Then you can have a counter that you increment by 1 on every reposition, and set `self.color=COLORS[self.counter%3]`. That gives you a nice cycle between the three colors.